# How to make a single plot from two dataframes with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I have 2 datasets, called A and B.
I want to compare the distribution of one common variable, called k, showing up in both dataset, but of different lengths (A contains 2000 values of k, while B has 1000, both have some N/A). So I would like to plot the distribution of A$k anf B$k in the same plot.

I have tried:

```
g1 <- ggplot(A, aes(x=A$k)) + geom_density()
g2 <- ggplot(B, aes(x=B$k)) + geom_density()
g <- g1 + g2
```

But then comes the error:

```
Don't know how to add o to a plot.
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: When making plots with `ggplot`, avoid using `$`. Also you should merge your data sets by either using a common ID or creating one. Or use the new data set in an `aes` call to a `geom` ie inside one `geom_density` use `data=data2,aes....`. eg `ggplot(A, aes(x=k)) + geom_density()+geom_density(data=B,aes(x=k)` You should however make your question [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: With `cowplot`: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we dont have any data it is hard to provide a specific solution that meets your scenario. But below is a general principle of what I think you trying to do.

The trick is to put your data together and have another column that identifies group A and group B. This is then used in the `aes()` argument in `ggplot`. Bearing in mind that combining your data frames might not be as simple as what I have done since you might have some extra columns etc.

```
# generating some pseudo data from a poisson distribution
A <- data.frame(k = rpois(2000, 4))
B <- data.frame(k = rpois(1000, 7))

# Create identifier
A$id <- "A"
B$id <- "B"

A_B <- rbind(A, B)

g <- ggplot(data = A_B, aes(x = k, 
                            group = id, colour = id, fill = id)) + # fill/colour aes is not required
  geom_density(alpha = 0.6) # alpha for some special effects

g
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you exactly that to do without knowing what data sets actually look like. But merging data sets into one then use `ggplot()` by specifying `group` or 'colour' would be one way to compare.

Another way is to use `grid.arrange()` from `gridExtra` package.

```
gridExtra::grid.arrange(g1, g2)
```

This is really easy and pretty convenient function. If you want to know more about gridExtra package, visit [this official document](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/gridExtra.pdf).